# SQL Server - can't remember the keywords for accessing inserted/deleted/updated during a query?

Tags: sql-server, insert, documentation

I know in SQL Server there is a way to get the inserted data, but I can't for the life of me seem to remember the keywords to use.

Running a query was something along the lines of this:

```
INSERT INTO table1
OUTPUT inserted.id1, inserted.id2 INTO someOtherTable
(id1, id2) VALUES (1,2)
```

And when googling for `output`, `inserted` or other similar keywords I keep finding pages on using the insert or output keyword from a stored procedure. I know I'm not crazy and this this exist. I'm just wondering if someone could point me to the documentation page for it?

Comment: [This is SQL Server Books Online on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130214.aspx) - it has **everything** on SQL Server ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the `inserted` & `deleted` tables in SQL Server.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx

Comment: ....which are **only** available in the scope of a **trigger** (and the original question has no reference to a trigger anywhere... ) ...

Comment: @marc_s that's true, but just because his question didn't explicitly state **trigger** doesn't necessarily mean that's not what he's looking for...

Comment: I believe this is what I was looking for. I was also able to find [this](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/88/posts/10128/output-clause-with-insert-update-and-delete-statements-in-sql-server-2005.aspx).